# Creating a Report with No Data in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a customer who has a requirement that they want the ability to print a blank report.  In an effort to accomplish this I've created a copy of my original report and removed my SQL queries, parameters, and fields; and have set all the fields to static text fields with underlines.  This would allow the user to print the report an manually fill in the form.

However, when I go to preview the report I only see the Title band.  I've tried setting the 'When No Data' field to all 4 different settings but no luck.  Does anyone have any pointers?

**Edit: Here is the beginning XML for reference**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.    net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FormD Blank" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="    552" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="d26d959f-1b4a-435a-a2e4-231bf461293c">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.3636363636363646"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFBFBF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[".\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
```

Comment: What happens when you add an impossible `WHERE` clause to the SQL queries, like `WHERE 1 = 2` ?

Comment: you must missed somthing. post your xml

Comment: When a put in a Where clause that forces no data to the report, then I get a completely blank (i.e. white) report.

Comment: Jasper has adding this feature to Jasper studio using the "one empty Record" data adapter and as they have "end of life" I-report you might want to start playing with it.     The other option i have done for this is in my sql replacing a field with "null as field name" not the best solution but easy enoff to do a find replace to create your Production version(very hard to go back to )

Answer (score 0):

I did confirm what Mike Noland had suggested.  That if you create an empty data source with one empty row then that works.

Here are the steps I took: [Creating a Blank iReport](http://www.treysargent.com/2014/08/creating-blank-report-in-ireport.html)